# Toggle not working when angular is introduced

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Faily new to the angular scene.
I have a toggle done in bootstrap below.
The toggle does not work when angular is simply added to the header with the `<script src>` tag

```
<li class="dropdown dropdown-quick-sidebar-toggler">
   <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle">
      <i class="icon-logout"></i>
   </a>
</li>

<div class="page-quick-sidebar-wrapper" data-close-on-body-click="false">
   <div class="page-quick-sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
         <li class="active">
            <a href="javascript:;" data-target="#quick_sidebar_tab_1" data-toggle="tab"> Modules</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
         <div class="tab-pane active page-quick-sidebar-chat" id="quick_sidebar_tab_1">
            <div class="page-quick-sidebar-chat-users" data-rail-color="#ddd" data-wrapper-class="page-quick-sidebar-list">
                <ul class="media-list list-items">
                   <li class="media">
                      <div class="media-body">
                      <h4 class="media-heading"><i class="fa fa-bank" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cash & Banking</h4>
                      </div>
                   </li>
                </ul>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Above works when angular is not introduced..but doesn't work when angular is included.

Any idea?

Comment: Any console errors/messages?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem when starting with angular, what fixed my problem was simply including a newer version of jquery.

Originally was using jquery 2.x and just changed it in my bower to 3.1.x

Comment: Thank you. You gave me an idea. Jquery was loading after angular. I simply made jquery load earlier and it worked. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Apparently jquery was being loaded after angular was.
Loading jquery before angular simply corrected it.